Data corruption in Windows Server VM on Proxmox
I ran into a strange data corruption issue in a VM running on Proxmox VE which I need help with. The VM in question is Windows Server 2016 Standard, used primarily as a file server.
On this VM, I found files which could not be read or copied anymore. I only get "the file is unreadable or damaged" - something I would expect from a defect physical disk. Since some of these files were downloaded, I downloaded them again and replaced the defective ones. That worked for this day, a few days later I found the same files defective again!
I began to take a closer look and ran a powershell script, trying to read all files on that disk - it revealed that there are ~300 defective files, scattered across all directories.
Even worse, I took a look on the backups on our PBS server - in addition to the defective files, I found more files in the backups which can be restored using file restore but contain only garbage, while the original on the server is still readable and OK. SHA256SUMs of original and backup differ. I have additional backups on usb disk, but since these cannot restore individual files, I would have to restore them completely to another VM to take a look.
Both problems are restricted to this VM disk - I ran the powershell script and checked the backups of other VMs, everything's fine. This is the second disk of this VM, the first one containing the OS is also fine.
The disk resides on a zfs mirror made up of two NVMe SSDs. 'zpool status' says everything OK, 'zpool scrub' also finds no problems. Backup verification on the pbs is on and also says everything OK. The VM is configured with VirtIO SCSI (not single), the disk is VirtIO block with discard on. VirtIO driver version is 100.74.104.14100 (I guess that is release 0.1.141?).
What freaks me out most is the backup corruption - until now I thought that verification on the pbs made sure that everything matches the source, but obviously that is not always true.
Any hints really welcome!

"I thought that verification on the pbs...." - you are correct. And the checksums managed by ZFS confirm this: the hypervisor wrote what the guest asked it to write. It provides no guarantee that the guest asked for the right thing.

Fix your machine. ZFS writes what it is told to. How should a file system know what is right or wrong? Its only job is to stay alive and do what is command ;) ed to the drive.

This smells like memory corruption. What is this machine physically? Do you have any alerts about ECC errors: APEI-related messages in the host's dmesg, something in the BMC's event log? Since it's ZFS and NVMe, I doubt BER of the disks is in play, but for the sake of completeness, check SMART and other status data of the storage media too.
